# Is there a way to check if an item exists in a Python tuple?

Tags: python, list, collections, tuples

I have seen an `index` function but it says it errors out if it can't find it. Is there a simple way to just check if the item exists? I just want to get a boolean value of the result so like:

```
if tuple.exists("item"):
    print "it exists"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `in` operator:

```
>>> 2 in (2, 3, 4)
True
```

`in` operator can be used to check for the membership of any element in a sequence.

And don't name your tuple as `tuple`. Use a different name.

Comment: I don't, that was just an example to show that I am invoking the function on a tuple.

Comment: @JoanVenge. Ok. I thought you were naming it that way. Then it's fine.

Comment: Also how would you do the negative `2 not in tuple`?

Comment: @JoanVenge to do the negation you use the `not` keyword as the logical operator. You can do something like this...
`2 not in (1, 3)` which evaluates as `True`. Conversely
`2 not in (1, 2, 3)` evaluates as `False`.